# Invalid character constant in Java/Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

In my code, I have a simple block:

```
final boolean isActivated = checkActivationStatus();
if (isActivated)
    return "index?/page1";
else
    return "index?/page2";
```

Eclipse show me an "invalid character constant" error here `(is`, and I don't know why.

I know, this is a repost question but all the others are asking about special characters like '\'.
Really don't understand this issue, so thanks to answer me anyway :3

[image: My Eclipse view]

Comment: Can you please post a screen shot of your eclipse ?

Comment: Are you missing a semi-colon somewhere, or just some other typo? Your code seems fine.

Comment: Your code works fine. Make sure the return type matches to a `String`

Comment: your code works in my machine...

Comment: Did you try and erase the line `if (isActivated)` and type it again? Sometimes non printable characters find their way in.

Comment: Added my Eclipse screen

Comment: By erase and rewrite the first semicolon, it works... Eclipse is mad guys... But thanks :D

Comment: Just save your file :D

Comment: this part of code is Ok, please, provide checkActivationStatus() and code above isActivated initialization

Comment: probably you copypasted some non-printable character right near the semicolon: I have the same problem when copypasting mvn dependencies from maven central in my pom in Intellij

Comment: Right, non-printable characters typically find their way into the editor when you copy and paste from a text document (PDF, DOC, HTML etc.) with special formatting. To check for yourself you should (temporarily) enable `Show Whitespace Characters`.